# Ajax IndexedDB Delete Current Sucesfull Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, indexeddb

I posted something similar yesterday but it works but only deleted the last object in the data.

**What I want to happen**

This ajax upload will be handling a lot of data, so I'm using indexeddb. This will also be use on mobile phones. So I wanted it to upload one item at a time and if one item failed to have only deleted the previous items out of the data so they wouldn't need to upload everything again.

I have tried async = false, This works exactly how i want it but this freezers browser.

**Current Code** Tried to comment out any bits that could be confusing, currently this only deletes the last item once finished.

```
function uploadData(e) {

 //Get Database 
 var transaction = db.transaction(["data"], "readonly");
 var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("data");
 var cursor = objectStore.openCursor();

 //Starts Looping
 cursor.onsuccess = function(e) {
     var res = e.target.result;
     if (res) {
         if (navigator.onLine) {
             $('.popup-heading').text('Uploading...');
             var passData = {
                 client_id: res.value.client_id,
                 parent_id: res.value.parent_id,
                 storename: res.value.storename,
                 image: res.value.image,
                 key: res.key,
             };
             var jsonData = JSON.stringify(passData);
             $.ajax({
                 url: "{{ path('destination_app_ajax') }}",
                 type: "post",
                 // Works but freezes browser 
                 /*async, flase*/
                 data: {
                     "json": passData
                 },
                 success: function(JsonData) {

                     //Delete item once successfull 
                     var t = db.transaction(["data"], "readwrite");
                     var request = t.objectStore("data").delete(passData.key);
                     t.oncomplete = function(event) {
                         console.log('item deleted');
                     };
                 },
                 error: function() {
                     $('.popup-heading').text('Upload Failed!');
                 }
             });
         } else {
             $('.popup-heading').text('Please find stronger signal or wifi connection');
         }
         res.
         continue ();
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: This IDB code looks generally correct. The problem is that it works but only sometimes? Can you describe again when it does and does not work? The `async` attribute on the jQuery object has to do with the request being async and not IndexedDB.  Could this be an ajax problem and not an IDB problem?

Comment: It was only deleting one object in ajax with there was 10 it looped through. It should of been deleting as they where successful. My solution was to pass the res.key to my php script then echo it back to delete.

Comment: Where's the loop? It sounds like you have a scope issue wherever you've defined `passData`, but I can't see this code in what's included above.

Comment: cursor.onsuccess = function(e) {
           var res = e.target.result;
           if(res) {  <- I thought this starts the loop?

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a scope issue with `passData`. Inside of your loop, but before you defined `var passData = ...` try wrapping the codeblock with an anonymous function:

```
(function() {
   /* Your code here */
}());
```

That should prevent `passData` from leaking into the global scope, which seems to be why your IDB code only works on the last loop. (`passData` is being redefined each time before your AJAX response is able to complete.)

**Update**: There is no loop, you're dealing with callbacks. What I see happening is that you're redefining your `onsuccess` handler on each Ajax request (and overwriting all values but the last), reusing the same transaction. Try moving this transaction code into the success callback for the AJAX request:

```
//Get Database 
 var transaction = db.transaction(["data"], "readonly");
 var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("data");
 var cursor = objectStore.openCursor();
```

That will create a closure and commit your `delete` transaction on each response. That means one transaction per AJAX request, and one `onsuccess` callback per AJAX request (with no redefining).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found worked with this was to send the Key via ajax to php then delete from that.

**HTML**

```
var passData = {     
                        .......
                        key: res.key,
                    };

.....

   $.ajax({
                       url: "yourscript.php",
                       type: "post",
                       data: {
                           "json": passData 
                       },

                       success: function(JsonData) {

                           jsonKey = JSON.parse(JsonData);


                           //Delete item once successfull 
                           var t = db.transaction(["data"], "readwrite");
                           var request = t.objectStore("data").delete(parseInt(jsonKey.key));
                           t.oncomplete = function(event) {
                            console.log('item deleted', jsonKey.key);
                           };



                       }
```

**PHP**

```
    $data = $_POST['json'];


    $returnKey =  json_encode(
                    array(
                            'key' => $data['key']
                    )
    );
```