# Error "A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations." when trying to open a transaction inside success event of ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, indexeddb

I just started my research on indexeddb for storing the data on the client-side. I was able to perform basic CRUD operations so I started to code the actual implementation case where user should retrieve the data from server in the form of json and then store it in the indexedDB objectStore. Now this is where I am facing problem, I know both ajax and transactions in IndexedDB  are async ,so I'm calling transactions in the success event, it throws me error saying "InvalidStateError : A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations." on the line where I call transaction to open.
Here is the javascript code and the json file

```
// Javascript IndexedDB start 
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;
var IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

// open db
var dbase;
var gotWidgetTemplates = false;
var widgetTemplets;
function init() {
    var databaseName = "ADTClientDB";
    var databaseVersion = 1;
    var open = indexedDB.open(databaseName, databaseVersion);
    open.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
       if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("WidgetTemplate")) {
        var widgetTemplateObj = db.createObjectStore("WidgetTemplate", { 
  keyPath: 'name' });
        widgetTemplateObj.createIndex("image", "image", { unique: false });
        widgetTemplateObj.createIndex("html", "html", { unique: false });
        widgetTemplateObj.createIndex("css", "css", { unique: false });
        widgetTemplateObj.createIndex("rules", "rules", { multiEntry: true });
    }

}
open.onsuccess = function (e1) {
    dbase = e1.target.result;
     getTemplates(dbase);
      dbase.close();
}
open.onerror = function () {
    alert("Error opening the database");
}
function getTemplates(dbase) {
 $.ajax({
        url: "../Sample Json files/widgetTemplates.json",
        type: "GET",
        success:
            function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                widgetTemplets = obj.widgets_info;
                gotWidgetTemplates = true;
                if (gotWidgetTemplates && widgetTemplets !== null) {
                 // I tried putting the transaction and store here,it was giving me same error..
                    for (var temp in widgetTemplets) {
                        // error on the next line
                        var trans = dbase.transaction(["WidgetTemplate"], "readwrite");
                        var store = trans.objectStore("WidgetTemplate");
                        store.add(widgetTemplets[temp]);
                    }
                }
            },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried putting setTimeout() like this

```
function addTemps(dbase) {
   if (gotWidgetTemplates && widgetTemplets !== null) {
      var trans = dbase.transaction(["WidgetTemplate"], "readwrite");
      var store = trans.objectStore("WidgetTemplate");
      for (var temp in widgetTemplets) {         
         store.add(widgetTemplets[temp]);
      }
   }
   else {
      setTimeout(addTemps, 7000);
   }  
}
```

Still it gives me either same error on the line of creating transaction or "tooManyRecursions" error.
 I tried putting promise into this like

```
      $.get("../Sample Json files/widgetTemplates.json").then(
            function (data0) {
                console.log(data0);
                var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data0));
                widgetTemplets = obj.widgets_info;
                var trans1 = dbase.transaction(["WidgetTemplate"], "readwrite");
                var store1 = trans1.objectStore("WidgetTemplate");
                for (var temp in widgetTemplets) {
                    store1.add(widgetTemplets[temp]);
                }
                console.log(obj);
            }, function (xhr, state, error) {
            debugger;
            console.log(arguments);
        });
```

It gives me same error on the transaction line.
Here is the json

```
{
  "widgets_info": [
        {
          "name": "TextInput",
          "image": "TEXTINPUT.PNG",
          "html": "<label for=\"uname\">LABEL</label>  <input type=\"text\" id = \"uname\" name=\"uname\">",
          "css": "{width : 30%; height:10%;}",
          "rules": {
            "on the event of": [
              "NONE",
              "Single left mouse click"
            ],
            "do these": [
              "NONE",
              "Trigger behavior"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I could see a transaction is possible inside ajax success link ([Ajax IndexedDB Delete Current Sucesfull Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502655/ajax-indexeddb-delete-current-sucesfull-upload))
I want to know why I cannot achieve this.I tried what all I can do, I browsed all the stuff I can but I cannot find the solution. A solution/reason for this would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!!