# "InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations."

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, indexeddb

I'm trying to open a transaction inside then().It gives me exception.
Here is the code:

```
open.onsuccess = function (e1) {
 var dbase = e1.target.result;
$.get("https://www.uuidgenerator.net/api/version4").then(
        function (message) {
            debugger;
            var projectData = { "uid": message, "name": "appName", "pages": [] };
            var trans = dbase.transaction(["Project"], "readwrite"); // error over here
            var store = trans.objectStore("Project");
            var projectAddReq = store.add(projectData);
            projectAddReq.onsuccess = function (e) {
                console.log("added project name into the database");
            }
            projectAddReq.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log("error adding project name into the database");
            }
        });
}
```

Can someone help me, why is the error occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening a connection to the database after the fetch, and not using an IDBDatabase variable instantiated at a different time.

Comment: I thought that's possible looking into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502655/ajax-indexeddb-delete-current-sucesfull-upload) .

Comment: it is possible, but if you are already confused, i suggest for now doing it the safe way that is guaranteed to work